# Using dbms_crypto on cloud APEX instance

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I'm in doubt for using dbms_crypto on my apex application.

On premise i use

```
grant execute on sys.dbms_crypto to myuser;
```

to enable dbms_crypto.

On cloud service like https://apex.oracle.com or other oracle services dbms_crypto is enabled by default?
Can i execute grant manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK is not possible to use dbms_crypto on apex.oracle.com.
However, there is a post in oracle forums that suggests you can ask for the grant: https://community.oracle.com/message/10967002

Good luck.

Comment: The link is broken